# How do I get the tab button to focus on a checkbox element in my HTML form?

Tags: html, forms

I tried giving the checkbox a tabIndex but that didn't seem to affect anything.

Comment: Post the code for your form please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use javascript in order to do that.

```
// jquery example
$('#elementid').focus();
```

A [tabindex, like the name says](http://webdesign.about.com/od/usability/a/aa071105.htm), works for the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key.

Comment: It turned out to be a weird issue: http://www.tonyspencer.com/2006/05/02/tab-skips-select-form-fields-in-mac-browsers/